# Store an image using UIImage from NSURL

Tags: objective-c, ios

USing UIImage, I know we can store an image from a URL. But I am currently stuck at some point where its not working for me.
I am trying to grab the image from the URL as shown below:

```
NSString *filename = @"12121212" 
UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/devlopment.cfm?method=%@",fileName]];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: logoImage];
```

I am sure, I am getting the image but cannot load it.

Am I going the correct way?

Sagos

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You'll need to use `UIImage`'s [`+imageWithData:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIImage_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006890-CH3-SW13) method and `NSData`'s [`+dataWithContentsOfURL:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000172-BBCGJEAC) method:

```
NSString *fileName = @"12121212";
NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/devlopment.cfm?method=%@",fileName];
UIImage *im = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:filePath]]];
```

Comment: Thanks Jacob for the quick reply. I did figure out my error but again stuck at UIImage length issue. I did change the width and height of each images to the static value. but it is still giving me errors.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you have things in a sort of backwards order. Setting `UIImage *logoImage` should be the last part. Additionally, turning a URL into an image is sort of a two step process.

First you need to get the data:

```
NSString *filename = @"12121212"; 
NSURL *tempURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.example.com/devlopment.cfm?method=%@",fileName]];
NSData *tempData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfUrl:tempURL];
```

Now you need to make it into an image:

```
UIImage *logoImage = [UIImage imageWithData:tempData];
```

I'm sure this code leaks and it doesn't handle network problems but you get the picture.

Comment: Whoops. I didn't see Jacob's answer before I was done with mine. Sorry for the extra posting.